# Inconsistant/Bad pings to router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ping

I have a desktop pc on wifi (yes, wifi. no ethernet jack) connected to my home network. The problem is that my internet has been really bad lately, and I ran some pings and they are all of the place. Pings to my router vary from 0.4ms to over 50ms. I ran the same thing on another laptop on WiFI and got pings under 2ms consistantly. What could be the problem? This is a new issue.

Answer (score 0):

Under 80ms is typical for wifi. I would not worry about 50ms pings. Likely the difference is a change in RF environment, e.g. your neighbor has a new wifi setup, somebody else is using the same channel you are, or any other interference on the 2.4 or 5Ghz band. Any interference will cause 'sporadic' jumps in ping latency as re-transmit is based on a timer that must expire at least once e.g. "The router didn't acknowledge it heard me within X milliseconds. Send the ping again!" It may take more than a few tries, especially if signal is weak and interference is high. If you get closer to the router, the ping should become more consistent.